# Is there any way to check if cursor return no record?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote simple program in **PL/SQL** to reduce price. When I call procedure I intentionally pass arguments which are not in database, so cursor doesn't return any data.
Here is problem: my exception not working. Expression like `kursor%notfound` check if kursor not returns any data or is not declared?
I am confused, because while I was doing research some people said that `kursor%notfound` returns true when there is no data found, but in my program it doesn't work. When it comes to this:

```
 if (kursor%notfound) then
        raise no_data_found;
    end if;
```

It doesn't raise exception. What am I doing wrong?
PS Sorry for inconsistency according to language(mixing polish and english) , but I have database in polish.

**My whole program:**

```
  set serveroutput on
create or replace procedure reduce_price(surname_p varchar2,
name_p varchar2, percents number default 5)is

cursor kursor is
    select n.id_mech,cena  from naprawa n
    join mechanik m on m.id_mech = n.id_mech
    where m.imie = name_p and m.nazwisko = surname_p
    for update;
nc number;
begin
    for k in kursor
    loop
       if (kursor%notfound) then
            raise NO_DATA_FOUND;
        end if;
    begin
        
        nc := k.cena *(1-percents/100);
        dbms_output.put_line(k.cena ||' ' ||nc);
        update naprawa set cena =nc
        where id_mech = k.id_mech;
    
        exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then
            dbms_output.put_line('no rows found');
    end;
    end loop;    
    
end;

/
begin
  reduce_price('aaa', 'XYZ',1);
end;
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @OldProgrammer's answer explains why it would never raise NO_DATA_FOUND, but another issue in the original code is that there is no exception handler at the scope of the RAISE statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not going to work. in your cursor for loop, if your code enters the loop, then  that implies that one or more records where found, and %notfound cursor attribute will never be true.  You have a couple of options.

1. keep a counter in the loop and check after exit

   create or replace procedure reduce_price(surname_p varchar2,
   name_p varchar2, percents number default 5)is

   ```
    nc number;
    cnt number := 0;
    begin
        for k in kursor
        loop

            nc := k.cena *(1-percents/100);
            dbms_output.put_line(k.cena ||' ' ||nc);
            update naprawa set cena =nc
            where id_mech = k.id_mech;
            cnt := cnt + 1;
        end loop; 

        if cnt = 0 then   
           raise NO_DATA_FOUND;
        end if;
    .. etc..
   ```
2. check for a existing data before entering the loop

```
    select count(*)
    into cnt
    from naprawa n
        join mechanik m on m.id_mech = n.id_mech
    where m.imie = name_p and m.nazwisko = surname_p;
    
           if cnt = 0 then   
                   raise NO_DATA_FOUND;
                end if;
            ...
         for k in kursor
          loop
```

Comment: (sorry having problems formatting the code in the answer for some reason)

Comment: None of this works. In both cases the result is: 
Procedure REDUCE_PRICE compiled
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: I don't have any exception raised even though I have no data in my db which I pass to procedure  :(

Comment: I though that maybe problem is using sql developer, but I don' t think so, in simplier programs exceptions worked.

Comment: Compiling a procedure does not execute the code in it.  If you are using sqldeveloper, then you can step through the code in the [debugger](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r51/testing_and_debugging_sqldeveloper/testing_and_debugging_sqldeveloper.html). Or put more dbms_output calls in your code to print the counter values, etc.

Comment: But after I compile procedure I run reduce_price('param1','param2',3). Now I see that for some reason program works the seme even if I commented almost all of lines even though I have 'create and REPLACE'. I will check out debbuger as you said.

Comment: Ok, it works! I just had to restart sql developer, it probably got stuck or crushed for some reason. Both of solutions your works fine in my code. Thank you a lot, now I understand it<3